# How can a foreign key be mapped onto an object field in SQLite-Net Extensions?

Tags: c#, sqlite, c#-4.0, sqlite-net, sqlite-net-extensions

**Context:**
We are using `SQLite-Net Extensions` for local data caching with `Xamarin`. We plan on deploying to iOS, Android and Windows Phone. We have existing data structures used throughout our system (all implementing a common interface) that we would like to store in this manner.

**Problem**
As shown in the code sample, the `[ManyToOne]` attribute is used to signify a relation field. This does not work. As described on the [BitBucket Developer Page](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions) the `[ForeignKey]` attribute can be used to specify the foreign key relation. This seemingly only supports an `int`. Can we easily adapt our structure to support these relations without duplicating the properties for the Id field. e.g. the following is undesirable.

```
    [ForeignKey(typeof(Address))]
    public int AddressId { set; get; }

    [ManyToOne]
    public Address Address
    {
        set { address = value; }
        get { return address; }
    }
```

**Code Sample**

```
using SQLite.Net.Attributes;
using SQLiteNetExtensions.Attributes;

namespace Data
{
    [Table("Client")]
    public class Client : IData
    {
        private int id = -1;
        private Address address = null;

        public Client() { }

        public Client(int id)
        {
            this.id = id;
        }

        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, Column("_id")]
        public int Id
        {
            set { id = value; }
            get { return id; }
        }

        [ManyToOne]
        public Address Address
        {
            set { address = value; }
            get { return address; }
        }
    }

    [Table("Address")]
    public class Address : IIdentifiable
    {
        private int id = -1;
        private string someFields = "";

        public Address() { }

        public Address(int id)
        {
            this.id = id;
        }

        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, Column("_id")]
        public int Id
        {
            set { id = value; }
            get { return id; }
        }

        public string SomeFields
        {
            set { someFields = value; }
            get { return someFields; }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite-Net Extensions is a thin layer over SQLite-Net, and it uses sqlite database for the storage. Relational databases store relations using foreign keys, and sqlite is no different in this aspect. Therefore, SQLite-Net and SQLite-Net Extensions also uses the foreign key mechanism for declaring relationships.

As an alternative, you could use intermediate tables to store relationships, the same way `ManyToMany` relationships work, but limit one of the ends to one. This way you would mimic a `OneToMany`, `ManyToOne` or even `OneToOne` relationship using ManyToMany relationships and intermediate tables. For example:

```
[Table("Client")]
public class Client {

    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, Column("_id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Ignore] // This property shouldn't be persisted
    public Address Address { get; set; }

    // This relationship is in fact a ManyToOne relationship,
    // but we model it as a ManyToMany to avoid adding foreign key to this entity
    [ManyToMany(typeof(AddressesClients))]
    public Address[] Addresses { 
        get { return Address != null ? new []{ Address } : Address; } 
        set { Address = value.FirstOrDefault(); }
    }
}

[Table("Address")]
public class Address
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, Column("_id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string SomeFields { get; set; }

    [ManyToMany(typeof(AddressesClients), ReadOnly = true)]
    public List<Client> Clients { get; set; }
}

// Intermediate table that defines the relationship between Address and Client
class AddressesClients {
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(Client))]
    public int ClientId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(Address))]
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
}
```

Of course, this would have some performance penalties.

As for the `PrimaryKey`, you can use any supported type, and you have to use the exact same type for the opposite `ForeignKey`, i.e. if you use `Guid` as primary key, the foreign key that *points* to that class must be a `Guid` too . In the demo project we're already using `int` (the most performant), `string` and even `UUID`.

Comment: Although this isn't the solution we chose, it is similar. In our case we forked the sqlite-net-extensions repository and modified it. We added a new custom attribute to indicate a foreign key. We then modified the internal read/write operations so that every time the attribute is detected, it writes to a custom Relations table, storing: source table, field, object id and the target object id.